# Format and remove the leading zero - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this data-frame:

```
   Var    count        mean        std
  Var1  33214.0 -216.687166 -24.076352
  Var2  55381.0 -130.082888 -18.583270
  Var3  67469.0   46.732620  15.577540
  Var4  55191.0  133.425134  66.712567
  Var5  46297.0   -0.240642  -0.048128
  Var6   1700.0   -9.200535  -4.600267
  Var7    998.0  263.906417  37.700917
  Var8     45.0  -11.759358  -2.351872
  Var9   2889.0    0.280749   0.140374
 Var10   7353.0  216.684492  43.336898
```

I want to remove the leading zeros in columns `mean` and `std`, also to remain with 3 digits after the decimal point (after rounding them).
In column `Var` I want to remove the digits after the decimal point.

Expected result:

```
   Var  count     mean     std
  Var1  33214 -216.687 -24.076
  Var2  55381 -130.083 -18.583
  Var3  67469   46.733  15.578
  Var4  55191  133.425  66.713
  Var5  46297    -.241   -.048
  Var6   1700   -9.201  -4.600
  Var7    998  263.906  37.701
  Var8     45  -11.759  -2.352
  Var9   2889     .281    .140
 Var10   7353  216.684  43.337
```

Comment: you'll have strings then, you okay with that?

Comment: Could I export that table to MS Word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `round()`, `astype(str)` and `replace` to get your target columns.

```
df[['mean','std']] = df[['mean','std']].round(3).astype(str).replace('^(-)0.|^0.',r'\1.',regex=True)
```

Note, these columns will be strings now, if you format them as floats the 0 will rightly appear. I'm unaware of any formatting methods that remove the 0

```
print(df)
      Var    count      mean      std
0   Var1  33214.0  -216.687  -24.076
1   Var2  55381.0  -130.083  -18.583
2   Var3  67469.0    46.733   15.578
3   Var4  55191.0   133.425   66.713
4   Var5  46297.0     -.241    -.048
5   Var6   1700.0    -9.201     -4.6
6   Var7    998.0   263.906   37.701
7   Var8     45.0   -11.759   -2.352
8   Var9   2889.0      .281      .14
9  Var10   7353.0   216.684   43.337
```

### Edit

To pad 0 on the right side of the decimal we will need to split and re-shape the columns.

I've added a single value with `0000.0000` to test.

```
s = df[['mean','std']].stack().str.split('.',expand=True)

s[2] = s[0] + '.' + s[1].str.ljust(3,'0')

df[['mean','std']] = s.drop([0,1],1).unstack()


     Var    count      mean      std
0   Var1  33214.0  -216.687  -24.076
1   Var2  55381.0  -130.083  -18.583
2   Var3  67469.0    46.733   15.578
3   Var4  55191.0   133.425   66.713
4   Var5  46297.0     -.241    -.048
5   Var6   1700.0    -9.201   -4.600
6   Var7    998.0   263.906   37.701
7   Var8     45.0   -11.759   -2.352
8   Var9   2889.0      .281     .140
9  Var10   7353.0      .000   43.337
```

Comment: What about this number? `-130.082888` (Row 1, column `mean`)

Comment: Thanks. What does the `'\1.'` mean?

Comment: @qwerty its a regex expression, it means to replace any matches with the first capturing group, in this instance is the `-` negative marker, if it doesn't exist its ignored so it works well in this instance.

Comment: OK. Last issue: if the number is `0.000000` so it transform that to `.0`. Could you please provide a solution for this? (To transform it to `.000` like the others.)

Answer (score 0):

```
# round to 3 digits (it will round on all your columns)
df = df.round(3)

# will convert count to an int and remove the decimal values
df["mean"] = int(df["mean"])
```

If you want to remove the leading 0, you will have to convert your values to string. But is it something you want to do ?

Comment: Yes, as long as I can copy the table to MS Word.